# User reported "Server busy" error in android when contacting server -- haven't found anything googling this however

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I have a couple of feedback messages set up in my android application, but "Server busy" is not one of them. A user reported having this error and needing to try to contact the server 3 times before he could make a successful connection.

Googling this has not come up with much, and I'm not sure where the problem lies. What I'm doing is contacting a php script with some post data and it comes back with sent or failed. I only show the user some pre-set messages in case of failure though, and since Server Busy is not one of them I assume this message is from the android OS?

Can anyone shed some light on what could be causing this? I haven't seen it myself and we've only just started a pilot for the apps/software.

Comment: server busy could be coming from a proxy sitting in front of your server. are you using apache? apache can also return this error (if set up to do so)

Comment: It is very likely a message returned by your web server and not android. Try to make the same requests as do your app from your desktop browser and see what happens. Check your server logs as well.

Comment: @lukas We are using apache, but I am not showing a webpage, or passing along any info back to user aside from my pre-set messages based on success or failure of the script. My app is working just fine (At the moment) so I can't replicate it unfortunately.

I took a quick look at the logs folder on our 1&1 host, but I didn't see anything that stood out